# Facebook login error: Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I built a website with Ruby on Rails and want to use the facebook login. Using the [Ominauth-Facebook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook), I am enable to log in on my computer. But when several friends tested it, they all got the error in Chrome(similar to Safari saying “Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"):
[image]

It's odd because it works well in all browsers in each device of mine(desktop, iphone and laptop). On my rails config, I already set

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers[:'X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com"
```

Anything I probably missed?Thanks!

Update: the errors won't show up again if my friend somehow signed in successfully once. Even when he logout from FB and sign in on my sites. I think that's why it works all good for me

Comment: You find a solution for this?

Comment: @MattFordham Nope, it is still buggy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options/27970086#27970086 -- does that help?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Facebook doesn't want to users enter their authentication data in iframe on another site. It's done for security purposes. To avoid this you can try add to your link:

`:target => "_top"`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on the facebook canvas, In order to stop this occuring i had to remove all of the loginurl parameters, im using the php sdk.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

When i try to add scope, redirect_uri it fails with the error seen in the question. I checked everything matches up on the scope to the app settings and still no joy, cannot apply any parameters. However, without the parameters my app is able to authenticate.